# Delete file (if it exists) before saving

Tags: key-bindings, commands

My problem is that I can create, but not overwrite existing files.  This is [probably due to a bug](https://github.com/matteoserva/MegaFuse/issues/11) in [MegaFuse](https://github.com/matteoserva/MegaFuse).  Because of this, when I finish editing a file I must first save it under a different name, and then replace the original by hand.  Of course, **this also affects emacs' auto-save and backup, because it only functions well on the first attempt**.

I'd be happy enough with a function/command that could simply do:

```
delete-file <current-buffer-name>
write-file <current-buffer-name>
```

*(I'm still an early beginner on emacs matters, and I still don't understand lisp very well.)*

Btw, do you know any keybinding I could use for this command?

Answer (score 3):

The functions you want are `delete-file`:

> `(delete-file FILENAME &optional TRASH)`
>
> Delete file named FILENAME.  If it is a symlink, remove the symlink.
>   If file has multiple names, it continues to exist with the other names.
>   TRASH non-nil means to trash the file instead of deleting, provided
>   ‘delete-by-moving-to-trash’ is non-nil.
>
> When called interactively, TRASH is t if no prefix argument is given.
>   With a prefix argument, TRASH is nil.

and `buffer-file-name`:

> `(buffer-file-name &optional BUFFER)`
>
> Return name of file BUFFER is visiting, or nil if none.
>   No argument or nil as argument means use the current buffer.

We can can combine them into a function, making sure that `buffer-file-name` is non-`nil` before we try to delete it. This function could also run `save-buffer`, but it sounds like what you really want is to always delete the file just before saving it, which is what `before-save-hook` is for

```
(defun delete-if-file ()
  (if (buffer-file-name)
      (delete-file (buffer-file-name))
    ))

(add-hook 'before-save-hook #'delete-if-file)
```

I haven't really tested this except to check that files are getting saved.  Since it deletes things, you should be careful.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Just a note though, I think `(true-filename buffer-file-name)` would be more appropriate than simply `(buffer-file-name)` because it avoids destroying symlinks.

Comment: Good point. I hadn't thought about symlinks.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs works like this by default: when it saves a file, it moves the existing file to the backup file (`rename("foo", "foo~")`), which unlinks the backup file, and it creates a new file to write to. This is controlled by the [`backup-by-copying`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Rename-or-Copy.html#index-backup_002dby_002dcopying) variable; the default value is `nil`, meaning the rename-and-new strategy.

There are a number of circumstances when Emacs will instead copy the existing file to the backup file (`open("foo~`", O_TRUNC)`) then save the buffer to the existing file (`open("foo`", O_TRUNC)`), basically when Emacs thinks it won't be able to create a file with the same permissions or hard links.

Auto-save files are in your home directory by default, so they aren't a problem.

Seeing the [bug](https://github.com/matteoserva/MegaFuse/issues/11), I suspect that your problem is not in fact that you *cannot* write the file, but rather that the filesystem advertises the file as read-only. If that's the case, then Emacs would believe that it can't re-create the file (which is a bit weird: Emacs applies the copy-and-overwrite strategy if it doesn't have the permission to overwrite the file!), which is one of the conditions that make it apply the copy-and-overwrite strategy.

Here's some heavy-handed code that forces Emacs to use the rename strategy in that case. Untested.

```
(defadvice backup-buffer
  (around backup-buffer-by-renaming-on-megafuse activate)
  (if (save-match-data
        (string-match megafuse-directory-regexp (file-chase-links buffer-file-name)))
      (letf (((symbol-function 'backup-buffer-copy)
              (lambda (from-name to-name modes extended-attributes)
                (rename-file from-name to-name t))))
        ad-do-it)
    ad-do-it))
```