# latex temp file cleanup

Tags: org-export

When using org for latex workflow, I like my directory (reasonably) clean.

Towards that I changed the default value of `org-latex-pdf-process` from

```
("latexmk -f -pdf -%latex -interaction=nonstopmode %f")
```

to

```
("latexmk -f -pdf -%latex -interaction=nonstopmode -auxdir=%oauxdir %f")
```

ie. I added an auxdir called `./auxdir`

That works for all the latex generated files, but not for the `.tex` file itself.

What should I do to keep the tex file also in `auxdir`?

---

Other similar Q/A like [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/78478/how-can-i-remove-the-tex-file-after-generating-pdf-using-org-latex-export-to-pd) all seem to talk of deleting. I dont want a delete but a keep-out-of-current-dir option

---

Currently Ive just done this:

```
(setq org-latex-pdf-process 
     '("latexmk -f -pdf -%latex -interaction=nonstopmode -auxdir=%oauxdir %f"
      "mv %F %oauxdir"))
```

but Im hoping for something cleaner

Comment: Surely this is a LaTeX question, not an Emacs question. Try asking it on StackOverflow or in some LaTeX–specific forum.

Comment: @db48x Its an org mode question. It's hardly a latex question since for latex users `.tex` files are source whereas for org users they are an intermediate format

Comment: Your current workaround is as clean as it gets, unless you modify the Org mode code. The current export code produces the exported file in the same directory as the Org mode file (and not just for LaTeX): there is no provision to put it anywhere else, so you have to do it by hand.